# Css Site display correctly at firefox and chrome and Doesn't Display Correctly in IE11

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

Css Site display correctly at Firefox and chrome and Css  Doesn't Display Correctly with IE11,the  breadcrumb that  i have in the header does not display correctly at ie11 i don't know why .

www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to used the css that work for all browsers. linear-gradient property is only for very few browser that support but not all.

```
background: your-color; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, your-color, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, your-color); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(white, your-color); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */ 
background: linear-gradient(top, your-color, white); /* Standard syntax */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, your-color, your-color); /* IE ? */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, your-color, your-color); /* IE 11 */
```

if you use these background property than it will work for all browser. Mean compatible property will auto work nature browser.

Comment: i have another property border-radius not working good in ie 11

Comment: border-radius is css3 property and IE 10,11 support this property but sometime missing pixels issue. Anyway try following property as well: -ms-border-radius: 10px;

Answer (score 0):

Issue in question is cross browser gradient:
Replace following css for background.

```css
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%, #207cca 0%, #b89470 0%, #b89470 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(0%,#207cca), color-stop(0%,#b89470), color-stop(100%,#b89470)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 0%,#b89470 0%,#b89470 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 0%,#b89470 0%,#b89470 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 0%,#b89470 0%,#b89470 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 0%,#b89470 0%,#b89470 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#b89470',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */***
```